# javascript load mvc @renderPage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I use `@RenderPage` with JavaScript or jQuery page load? I've tried this but it's not working:

```
$("#ActivePageContent").load('@RenderPage("/Views/Port.cshtml")');
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing server-side with client-side code. `@RenderPage` is just going to dump the rendered HTML of your view directly into `Response`. You can examine the source of your page to verify. You'll have something that looks a lot like...

```
$("#ActivePageContent").load('<html><head><title>Some Page</title>...');
```

It's unclear what you're really trying to do with your jQuery `load()` method, but `@RenderPage` isn't going to get you there.

From [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/load/), `load()` is supposed to take a URL:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html" );
```

Maybe you meant to write something like this instead?

```
$("#ActivePageContent").load('@Url.Action("Port", "MyController")');
```

Comment: ok but I've tried it yet not working http://blog.devlpr.net/2011/01/03/jquery-load-with-mvc-2-partialviews/

Comment: In the example you linked `load()` is taking a URL. It's misleading because the URL says *PartialView* in it, but it's still a URL. Try using the `UrlHelper` method `Url.Action()` instead, which will produce a URL to an action method on a controller.